# Login broken without JavaScript (submit button can't be clicked)

Tags: bug, login, javascript

Trying to log in with JavaScript disabled does not work.  Using a Stack Exchange email and password, the "Log in" button does nothing.  This is likely because the `<input type="button">` instead of standard HTML `type="submit"`, which doesn't trigger a POST.

However, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does submit the form and let me login.

Comment: Disabling Javascript will sure break many things. The answer given here is somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128404/254554

Comment: Maybe the question is different, the answer on the duplicate is a 100% fit

Comment: @Rachie The other answer is sufficient for this, but please consider leaving this question in place (ie not delete) even if closed as dupe, as this is a good signpost leading to the other answer for others to find it :)

Comment: I keep seeing posts about how basic functionality should work without javascript.  This isn't about extra UI elements, but something completely essential to the use of the site.  There's no sense in breaking such basic HTML conventions for the sake of replacing it with buggy javascript.

Comment: Not dupe, not being able to log in at all is x100 worse than not being able to add a new OpenID provider when already logged in. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Trying to use the sites without JS is most certainly not recommended. Having said that, not being able to log in at all is suboptimal. We'll be fixing this.

Comment: @Adam still not fixed.