# To what extent is SE usable with console browser, not supporting javascript and images?

Tags: support, user-interface

To what extent is SE usable with console browser, not supporting javascript and images? Say lynx/links/links2/elinks or something else?

I can live with javascript killed, but on some occasions when posting an answer captcha pops up and this bugs me, since answering is important.

Comment: I'd say "unknown" since SE team simply won't test with such browsers. Basic things like logging in and posting (questions and answers, not comments) should be supported though.

Comment: I'd suggest [Column 80](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-stack-exchange), a lynx-optimized interface to Stack Exchange sites, but it seems to be broken at the moment (at least from a non-lynx browser).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thanks. Haven't tried it yet. Does it support posting?

Answer (score 3):

Doing anything other than reading on SE requires Javascript. Period. I am sure those browsers aren't officially supported either.

Using a command line browsing tool for reading or writing [isn't officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/245360), while I think it would work most of time, unless you are facing captchas and so. Try to switch to the mobile site too, since it uses Javascript a lot less.

If you use that command line browser for scraping information within the boundaries of the ToS: the API is better suited for reading and writing from a self-made program, so if that is what you want, use the API.

Comment: Is there a list of supported browsers? And since when using console browser is scraping (AFAIK for scraping there are special purpose tools, not browsers)?.

Comment: You mean you really use that for just browsing SE? I only use those tools if I want to automate some actions.

Comment: [Supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/245360)

Comment: I don't mean to automate anything SE related. Some javascript enabled browsers can be automated too AFAICT.

Comment: The list of officially supported browsers refers to full support, i.e. with all features working. However, I've seen developers say more than once that any browser, no matter how odd, should be able to login and post - the core functionality of Q&A site, even without JS enabled.

Comment: Okay, a link would be useful. The mobile UI should be better suited anyway. @Sha

Comment: I will try to find, maybe those were only comments, but sure I saw it. :-)

Comment: I am fully aware that these browsers are not officially supported for full functionality, but I am not asking about this at all. Mentioning ToS/scraping also doesn't have anything to contribute to the question, perhaps except for your interpretation that people using different browsers are scapers/spammers.

Comment: @joro - you were not called a spammer. Even I do not use lynx to post at SE, you can check out **sx** extension for Emacs, though.

Comment: @DeerHunter Thanks. I use vim, but emacs as browser is an option. Does `sx` properly support ssl?

Comment: @joro - TLS support was the principal reason I chose it (hat tip @Gilles).

Comment: @Pat [found it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128404/152859) - only referring to JS though, not related to browsers. And especially [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128397/add-button-doesnt-work-with-javascript-off/128404#comment350423_128404).

Comment: Good find @sha. Thanks.